# On the rank of antisymmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, skew-symmetric-matrices

> Let $\Bbb F$ be a field, and $\mbox{char}(F) \neq 2$. Let $A$ be an antisymmetric matrix ($A^{T} = -A$). Show that $\mbox{rank}(A)$ is even.

---

I think the theorem bellow might help, but I don't know how to use it:

$T$ is a translation and $W$ is a vector space, $T: W \to W$ $$\mbox{rank}(T) + \mbox{null}(T) = \dim(W)$$

Comment: If all else fails, read http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf . (Theorem 5.1 + something earlier to reduce to the nondegenerate case.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Very good link: that's implied in my post, so I don't understand why you said you never heard such a thing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determinant of skew- symmetric matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531427/determinant-of-skew-symmetric-matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$\det A=\det A^T=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det A$$

and this much is true for any principal minor of the matrix, so if we have an odd numbered minor and $\;\text{char}\,\Bbb F\neq2\;$ , the determinant vanishes.

Comment: Why are *principal* minors enough?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Checking them you can find out what the matrix's rank is. Observe that the biggest pricipal minor is the whole matrix's determinant.

Comment: Judging by the *principal* minors alone, the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\ -1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$ would have rank $0$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg How come? The principal minor $\;2\times 2\;$ is $\;-1\;$ ...

Comment: Oops, my example was wrong. I'm still unconvinced of the claim...

Comment: Actually, drop the $-1$ and you get a non-skewsymmetric counterexample. Is there a reason why skew-symmetry should help?

Comment: It can perhaps help that what I mean is what some authors call *leading* (principal) minors, which are the upper left matrices.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Sorry, but if you drop the $\;-1\;$ in your example then the matrix is **not** anti-symmetric...

Comment: Yes, but why does anti-symmetry make the claim true? I've never heard of such a result...

Comment: @darijgrinberg Did you already google "minors", "principal minors" or something like that? You can find results there, I'm sure as it is more or less basic, that a matrix has rank$\;k\;$ iff one of its $\;k\,-$ minors is regular. I used *principal* minors taking advantage of the fact your matrix is antisymmetric.

Comment: This would entail that $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ has rank $2$ (all its principal minors of positive size are $0$), which is not the case. I think you are confusing skewsymmetric matrices with symmetric matrices somewhere (and also matrices over a field with matrices over $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg You're confusing me a lot: your matrix in your last comment **has rank two**  ! I think I'm going to stop this exchange as I see it goes nowhere. Thank you for the ideas. Hopefully the asker already got some useful ideas, here or there, for his question.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Just one little comment more to clear out my intention (which was probably foggy or unclear): by "principal minors" I mean the ones obtained from the original matrix by deleting the row $\;k\;$ **and also** the columns $\;k\;$ . If the matrix is denoted by $\;A\;$, minors many times are denoted by $\;A_{ij}\;$ (delete row $\;i\;$ and column $\;j\;$), so then the minors I mean are $\;A_{kk}\;$ . Hopefully this clears out doubts about naming. Sorry for that.

Comment: Oops, I meant that your statement would entail that the matrix has rank $0$. Sorry, my own typos don't help this very much...

Comment: @darijgrinberg Ok, now I see what you meant. Yet, in your last example matrix the  principal (or leading or whatever) minor $\;A_{11}=1\neq0\;$ ...

Comment: Yeah, because you mentioned the leading minors, which in this case are $0$. And yeah, I called them principal minors because I really should start proofreading my comments before I submit them :)

Comment: I am still curious about how you get your criterion with principal minors. I can confirm it in the case when the base field is $\mathbb{R}$, but the general proof is elusive.